# Data api ga, how to get data for multiple pages?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using Data api of google to get data in my filters, I'm getting data for page path for single page and I'm stuck at multiple pages. I followed document and passed following query to filters,

```
$filter = 'ga:pagePath=~/about_us.htm,ga:pagePath=~/index.htm';
```

Is there anything wrong in it? Can someone please help in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `$dimensions='ga:pagePath'` to individually query the two pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it but it's always good to run your data api calls through the [Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html). It will show you if it is getting results and show you the [proper url-encoded query](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filterExpressions).

I ran a query using the Data Feed Query Explorer on my site that was similar to yours and had no problems.