# Python to retrieve multiple pages of data from API with GET

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use Python 3 `requests.get` to retrieve the data from [this page](https://api.safecast.org/en-US/measurements?locale=en-US), using its API. I am interested in retrieving data from all the pages using the [API](https://api.safecast.org/en-US/home).

Here is my attempt so far

```
data = 'https://api.safecast.org/en-US/measurements'
data = requests.get(url)
```

My problem is the following - when I check the length of `data` using

```
len(data.json())
```

it gives me `25`. This is because there are 25 records per page and it is only returning page number 1. I need to retrieve data from all pages, not just page 1.

According to the [API](https://api.safecast.org/en-US/home), there are some parameters that can be specified in the query in order to filter the search. But, I do not know how to specify the page number in the query.

I looked through these 2 SO posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480680/get-data-from-multiple-pages-of-a-website), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525216/data-api-ga-how-to-get-data-for-multiple-pages)), but I could not find something relevant to my problem.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530172/4057186), I tried

```
print(data.links)
```

but this just gave `{}`

**Question**

Is there a way to collect data from all pages at once, using the API? Also, how do I determine the number of pages programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi As there are total 4458708 pages , you can add for loop and get json of each page. Check below code

```
import requests
for page in range(1,4458709):
    url = 'https://api.safecast.org/en-US/measurements.json?page=%s'%page
    data = requests.get(url)
    print data.json()
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to automatically determine the number of pages?

Comment: you can parse the response of data.content and get the total number of pages using below code `url= 'https://api.safecast.org/en-US/measurements'
data = requests.get(url)
print data.content` The content is in the form of html

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work with this and see what it can give me.