# Authenticated API Call Python + Pagination

Tags: python, api, pagination

I am making an authenticated API call in Python - and dealing with pagination. If I call each page separately, I can pull in each of the 20 pages of records and combine them into a dataframe, but it's obviously not a very efficient process and the code gets quite lengthy.

I found some instructions on here to retrieve all records across all pages -- and the json output confirms there are 20 total pages, ~4900 records -- but I'm still only, somehow, getting page 1 of the data. Any ideas on how I might pull each page into a single dataframe via a single call to the API?

Link I Referenced:
[Python to retrieve multiple pages of data from API with GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773904/python-to-retrieve-multiple-pages-of-data-from-api-with-get/53774024)

My Code:

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

for page in range (1,20):
url = "https://api.xxx.xxx...json?fields=keywords, source, campaign, per_page=250&date_range=all_time"
headers={"myauthkey"}

response=request.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.json()) #Shows Page 1, per_page: 25, total_pages: 20, total_records: 4900

data=response.json()

df=pd.json_normalize(data,'records')

df.info() #confirms I've only pulled in 250 records, 1 page of the 20 pages of data.
```

I've scoured the web and this site - and can't find a solution to efficiently pull in all 20 pages of data, except to call each page one-by-one. I think one solution might be looping through the code until the final page of data has been reached, but I'm not quite sure how to set that up and sort of thought the above might accomplish that - and maybe it does, but maybe the subsequent code I've written is not right to pull in all pages of data.

Appreciate any guidance/advice. Thanks!